# Get series and parallel pickup wirings from a Strat?

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups, wiring

I'm looking for a way to get some thicker pickups-in-series tones out of my Strat without losing the existing Strat sounds, or some extra ones I've added.

My current wiring uses one of the tone pots to dial the bridge pickup in while the neck pickup is engaged, giving N+M+B or N+B.  I really want to keep those tones with this rewire, while adding N+M and M+B in series.

Using a push-pull DPDT on one of the tone pots I can also get N+M in series, or N+M+B in series, but I'm finding the N+M+B in series is too loud compared to the single coil settings, so I'd like to get M+B or N+B in series instead.

Oh, and drilling the scratchplate is not an option, nor is using anything that doesn't *look* original.

Here's my current wiring - almost (the bridge-with-neck switch in that diagram is not quite accurate):
[image: current wiring]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like [Deaf Eddie's](http://www.deaf-eddie.net/) "FAT-O-Caster" mod, which provides (as of V3, in addition to standard tones):

- Neck and bridge in parallel, with or without middle in parallel;
- Bridge and neck in series, with or without middle in parallel; and
- Bridge (out-of-phase) and neck in series, with or without middle in parallel.

This switches out one of the tone controls for a 4-way rotary switch to provide the extra options. You can see the tone chart [here](http://www.deaf-eddie.net/tonecharts.html) and manual [here](http://www.deaf-eddie.net/fat-v3-m.html).

Answer (score 0):

This might be slightly off-topic, & I'm no wiring expert, but many years ago I dropped a Seymour Duncan Hot Rails into my '85 Squier. I did, unfortunately, drill it to get the extra 3-way switch in - these days I'd have been smarter & put a push-pull in there.

Might be worth a look - this page is all strat replacements
http://www.seymourduncan.com/products/electric/stratocaster/index.php?page=all
many more than when I did mine.

Comment: thanks.  My pickups are all Seymour Duncans.  I bought them so long ago (B.I. - before the internet) I can't really remember what they are.  Alnico 2 neck, Classic stack bridge, maybe.  They give good single coil tones by themselves.  But I'm after some additional wiring options to get beefier sounds.